# Combinatorial Proof - $\ {1 \over n+1} {2n\choose n} = {2n-1\choose n-1} - {2n-1\choose n+1} = {2n\choose n} - {2n\choose n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I'm been struggling with this proof for quite a while now - I'm trying to combinatorially prove this expression:

$$ {1 \over n+1} {2n\choose n} = {2n-1\choose n-1} - {2n-1\choose n+1}$$

$$= {2n\choose n} - {2n\choose n-1}$$

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I cleaned up your MathJax code.  Please look at it.  You have hyphens instead of minus signs, without proper spacing, because you kept alternating in and out of MathJax, and you put your "equals" signs outside of MathJax.  To people who know MathJax or TeX, it comes across looking like something written by someone who is spelling-challenged.  But +1 for the question.

Comment: The number at the left is a catalan number which has many combinatorial interpertations. Maybe you could find combinatorial in that way http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is easier to see in the form:

$$\binom{2n}{n}=(n+1)\binom{2n}{n}-(n+1)\binom{2n}{n-1}$$

We're going to be counting the number of ways to choose $n$ elements from $2n$, without "marking" any, as you will see in the next section. The left side clearly counts this.

On the right side, we go by complement. Our larger set we count is the set of ways to choose n elements from $2n$ where at most 1 is "marked". We do this by choosing $n$ elements, then either marking one of the $n$ or none ($n+1$ choices).

Now, all we need to subtract are the number of ways to choose $n$ elements and mark exactly one. First, choose $n-1$ unmarked elements, then from the remaining $n+1$, choose an element to mark and put in the set.

By counting by complement, we have counted the number of ways to choose $n$ unmarked elements, concluding the proof.

EDIT: Then we just divide both sides by $n+1$, *now* concluding the proof.

Comment: Thank you! By any chance, do you know of any resources to help me construct combinatorial proofs?

Comment: Honestly just a lot of practice. I really think the best way to solve these problems is to see many of them and figure out the tricks. For example, you usually don't want to have to deal with division, so multiplying by both sides gives something easier to work with. After that, you really just have to contemplate all possible meanings of numbers. If we see subtraction, what's the bigger set? If we see a summation, what on earth could we be partitioning on? Asking all these questions usually will lead closer to the combinatorial argument required.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the help - I'm reading Cohen's Introduction to Combinatorial Theory, and I understand the theory but when it comes to the problems, I'm completely lost. Thanks anyway!